# Edge HTML5 input type="date" breaks when the interval between value and min attribute is too big

Tags: html, input, microsoft-edge

I have an issue with an HTML5 input type="date" in edge only. The value is set at end of time, by default ("31.12.9999") and min is set to today. When opening the datepicker the page breaks, I guess it has something to do with the difference between the min date and the current value. Any idea of how I can avoid this?

See example:

```html
<input type="date" value="9999-12-31" min="2020-10-01">
```

Comment: '2020-10-01' is not today. It's in the future.

Comment: Yes, but the issue is the same, whenever the interval between min and value is to (big > 200 years, for me). I guess that edge somehow builds an array with all the dates in memory and tries to put all the values in the datepicker popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mention whether you are using the **MS Edge legacy browser** or the **MS Edge Chromium browser**.

Here, I assume that you are using the **MS Edge legacy browser**.

I have made a test with the **Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0** and looks like it is working properly.

[image]

I have also made a test with the **MS Edge (Chromium) browser version: 84.0.522.61** (Official Build) (64-bit). It also works fine.

[image]

- If you are using an older version of the MS Edge legacy browser then you can try to update it to the latest version may help to fix the issue.
- Try to check the issue on any other machine with the Edge browser may help to decide whether this is a machine-specific issue or not.
- Let us know if we are missing something or misunderstanding by providing some more information about the issue. We will try to provide further suggestions.

Comment: Yes, we are using Edge Legacy: Microsoft Edge 41.16299.1480.0          
Microsoft EdgeHTML 16.16299. I have tested on different machines using the same Edge version and the problem persists. We would have to find a workaround (I guess using JS) until a new version of Edge is deployed company wise.

Comment: MS Edge 41.x is an old version and upgrading to the latest version may help to fix the issue. I understand that you need a temporary fix until the latest version gets deployed by your company. If it is not necessary to use a wide range of values in the date picker then try to make a test with the smaller range and check whether it is working or not

Comment: Yes, with a smaller range it works fine. I have tested with 100 years - fine, 200 years - it breaks. We will go for a temporary fix until update of Edge is deployed.

Comment: You can continue with this workaround temporarily. If you think that answer is helpful and it can help to fix the issue then you can try to accept it as an answer to this question. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition of Input on the site [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) :

The latest date to accept. If the value entered into the element occurs afterward, the element fails constraint validation. If the value of the max attribute isn't a possible date string in the format yyyy-mm-dd, then the element has no maximum date value.

If both the max and min attributes are set, this value must be a date string later than or equal to the one in the min attribute.